# aTooltip not working for generated content

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am using [aToolTip](http://itsmeara.com/jquery/atooltip/) and coming across some strange behavior. May be a bug in Jquery?

The tooltip works fine if the link is generated by jquery directly. But if the link is triggered by a change event it doesn't work.

So this does not work:

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="thediv">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#sel" ).change(function() {

    var s = '<a href="#" class="fixedTip" title="tooltip text">some text</a>';
    $('#thediv').append(s);
});
</script>
```

but this works:

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="thediv">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var s = '<a href="#" class="fixedTip" title="tooltip text">some text</a>';
    $('#thediv').append(s);
</script>
```

i.e. the only difference is that the link being written is not triggered by the change in the select. I tried alert to check the html and it is identical.

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle.

Comment: You have to initialize tooltip plugin once element is added to the DOM. Here, element is added only when the select as fired change event. You didn't post how do you initialize plugin. BTW, when something doesn't work, it is rarely due to a bug but more often misused code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to re initialize the tooltip plugin for dynamically added elements , after it is added(appended)  to a DOM

try this

```
 $( "#sel" ).change(function() {

  var s = '<a href="#" class="fixedTip" title="tooltip text">some text</a>';
  $('#thediv').append(s);
    $('a.fixedTip').aToolTip();   //<---- here 
});
```

Comment: that worked. strange I had tried to load the tooltip js file at the end of the document instead of the head and it still didn't work so I assumed this was not the problem.